# Two versions of Docker data volumes on same machine?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm currently working on a project where we want to test the latest version of our dataset on our server. However, there's another build of the same Dockerized program with a different dataset currently running under `user_1`. I want to be able to run a second instance of the application as `user_2` using a different dataset, but I'm not sure if I can build the Docker images as `user_2` without stomping on `user_1`'s images, particularly the data volumes.

If I run `docker build` as `user_2`, would this destroy `user_1`'s existing images and data volumes? If so, what can I do to prop up a second instance of the application without destroying the data volumes?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Is user_1 an user inside the Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run docker build with another tag (like image:test).  If you're using named volumes, use another name for it in the Docker Compose YAML file.

If you're paranoid you can backup the image with docker-save and backup the volume as described in:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes